# Listview: How to edit only one of the label fields

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a listview that dynamically creates a list of items. In the list view, each member has 2 labels: a "rank" (a number, typically 1-10) and a "name". Each listview item also has 3 buttons. I want to make it so that the user is able to edit the "rank" label. If they are also able to edit the name label, then that is ok, but i would prefer just the one.

The answers I have seen online all involve the "LabelEdit" property of the ListView, however that does not seem to exist for me, as I get compile errors when I include that attribute.

Here is the Xaml for my ListView:

```
 <ListView Margin="134,110,100,50" 
              Name="carrierList" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              Width="232" 
              BorderBrush="LightGray" 
              BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
              Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowCarrierList, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding CarrierList}" 
              Grid.RowSpan="2" 
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment ="Stretch">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                    <!-- All rows -->
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5" />
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="165" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Rank}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CarrierName}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>


                        <Button  Width="20" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" ToolTip="Edit Carrier Details" Command="{Binding ElementName=carrierList, Path=DataContext.EditCarrierClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="{StaticResource EditImg}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        <Button  Width="20" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" ToolTip="View All Nodes With This Carrier" Command="{Binding ElementName=carrierList, Path=DataContext.AffectedNodeListClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="{StaticResource NetworkImg}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        <Button  Width="20" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" ToolTip="Remove Carrier From Node" Command="{Binding ElementName=carrierList, Path=DataContext.OnRemoveClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="{StaticResource ErrorImg}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: To edit, you need to find value, that you want to edit, in observableCollection, extract, change it and then insert.

Comment: I want the user to simply be able to click on the value and start typing. The information is already in an observeable collection (an observablecollection of Carrier objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the "Rank" Label with a TextBox and make sure that the "Rank" source property has a public setter:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="165" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Rank}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CarrierName}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
```